# How to output Javascript variable for Google map script

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to include a Javascript variable in a script for Google maps used in a Wordpress installation.

I've successfully set up the variable to get the directory uri, and want to add it to the uri for the map pin marker:

```
new google.maps.Marker({position:o,map:t,icon:'../images/icons/map_pin.png'});
```

Which is in an external script file. I've tried to use doc.write, but that doesn't work. How can get the variable to output?

Comment: *How* have you "tried to use doc.write"?

Comment: You can pass PHP variables to JS in Wordpress via [wp_localize_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/)

Comment: So there's no way to simply pull in the variable already set? Without setting up another function?